# Android Error while compiling

Tags: android

I get an error in which I can't understand. Can any one tell me what this means?

```
can't open /data/misc/hprof_oom_dump.hprof: Permission denied
```

Comment: did you do clean and build?

Comment: Being an android developer you must always, saveall, clean and build projects before getting panic...

Comment: wow question solved in 1 min......

Comment: glad if you would accept the answer! @SreekanthKarumanaghat

Comment: Gimme another 42 seconds ;)

Comment: @Nezam Is there any way I can understand the problem from the message shown? I mean does the message convey that the problem will be solved on a clean and restart.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat not exactly.There are many problems which may come up due to different reasons,target api change,jdk update,build path change,new library attached and so on.Some times eclipse ide might not detect them.This is where `clean` comes in.It forces the eclipse ide to start the build process from scratch.So generally whenever you come across any problem which aint going away..you should try this first before posting a query.Sorry for the looong comment though!

Comment: @Nezam Thanks..can you ping me at sreekanth100k@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `Clean and Build`. If that doesn't work, restart once.

Answer (score 0):

Restart and it should work perfectly fine!